# How can I get the user's selection's center anchor point position (x, y) relative to the document/window?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, frontend

How can I get the user's selection's center anchor point position (x, y) relative to the document/window?

I only know how to get selected nodes using `window.getSelection()`. But not the position:

[example use case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdsAC.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getBoundingClientRect()` for this purpose. To get the center point, add the half of width to the horizontal distance from the left edge of the screen.

```
let coords = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect()
let center = coords.x + (  coords.width / 2 )
```

To get the accurate vertical position from the top of the document.

```
coords.y + window.scrollY
```